# cs50 pset6 server parse function - does not pass cs50 server 1 check

Tags: parsing, server, cs50

Can you give some advise on what exactly are the errors indicated in cs50 check server1 and some guidance how to solve them:

my parse function looks like this:

```
bool parse(const char* line, char* abs_path, char* query)

{
   // create copy of line
   char linecopy[strlen(line)+1];
   strcpy(linecopy, line);
   linecopy[strlen(line)] = '\0';



 int spaces = 0;
   for (int i = 0, lenght = strlen(line); i < lenght; i++)
    {
    if (line[i] == ' ')
    spaces++;

    if (spaces > 2)
    {
        error(400);
        return false;
    }
    }
   char* methodcopy;
   char* targetcopy;
   char* httpcopy;

    // extract method, request-target, and http version to tokens
    methodcopy = strtok(linecopy, " ");
    targetcopy = strtok(NULL, " ");
    httpcopy = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");

    //copy tokens into method, target and http

    char method[strlen(methodcopy) + 1];
    strcpy (method, methodcopy);
    char target[strlen(targetcopy) + 1];
    strcpy(target, targetcopy);
    char http[strlen(httpcopy) + 1];
    strcpy(http, httpcopy);

    // add null terminators

    method[strlen(method)] = '\0';
    target[strlen(target)] = '\0';
    http[strlen(http)] = '\0';

    // ensure method is GET

    if(strncmp(method, "GET", 4)!= 0)
    {
        error(405);
    }
   // ensure request-target begins with "/"
   if(strchr(target, '/') == NULL)
   {
       error(501);

   }
    // ensure request-target does not contain '"'
    if (strchr(target, '"') != NULL)
        {
            error(400);
        }
   // ensure HTTP version is 1.1
   if(strcmp(http, "HTTP/1.1") != 0)
   {
       error(505);

   }

   // extract query from request-target
   char* abs_pathcopy;
   char* querycopy;
   abs_pathcopy = strtok(target, "?");
   querycopy = strtok(NULL, "\0");

   //if query isn't null, copy to query
   if (querycopy != NULL)
   {
       strcpy(abs_path, abs_pathcopy);
       strcpy(query, querycopy);

       abs_path[strlen(abs_pathcopy)] = '\0';
       query[strlen(querycopy)] = '\0';
   }
   //if query is null, set query to null
        else 
        {
            strcpy(abs_path, abs_pathcopy);
            abs_path[strlen(abs_pathcopy)] = '\0';
            query[0] = '\0';
        }
    // ensure absolute path does not contain "?"
    if(strchr(abs_path, '?') != NULL)
    {
        error(400);

    }
    // ensure query does not contain '"'

    if(strchr(abs_path, '"') != NULL)
    {
        error(400);

    }
    return true;
}
```

When I do the cs50 check server 1, I have the following errors indicated:

:( request-target of abc/hello.php returns error code 501
   \ expected output, but not "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type:..."

:( Requesting cat.exe returns error code 501
   \ expected output, not an exit code of 0

:( Two spaces after GET returns error code
   \ expected output, not an exit code of 0

as per my understanding, the request line is not as per the definition:

method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF

but not sure how to define it....

Any tips and advice are welcome! I do not want a solution, but just some indications ;)

Thanks to everyone who has taken the time to read this long question!

Answer (score 0):

You algorithm first assumes the input, line, is a well formed request than divide it into pieces, and than checks the divided parts. How do you now delimeter " " (SP) is exactly at correct places and in correct number? what if I never use a SP or use double SP everywhere?

In short, I do not think you should use strtok() with a string that you do not know about correctness of its form. Parse input char by char or use fuctions like [strchr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) to detect occurances of delimeter yourself.

Edit on use of strchr():

The document [strchr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) I linked for strchr() says "Returns a pointer to the first occurrence of character in the C string str.". So, If a have string like "one*two*three*four\0" where '*' is the delimeter;

```
char* firstStar =strchr(myString, '*')
```

will return a pointer that points to the first star,

```
char* secondStar =strchr(firstStar + 1, '*')
```

will return the second star because you said start seaching from the firstStar.
 This function returns null if it can't find the character you specified.
 (See the example at given link)

Now I can retrieve second paramater "two" by using [strncpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) function because I know where it starts (at firstStar +1) and how long it is (secondStar  - firstStar) Note that after you use strncpy() you should put null terminator '\0' manually at the end of copied string.

Comment: @ t.m. -  thanks! I followed your advice and edited my code in the beginning and checked for number of spaces in the request line and this solved one of the errors(:( Two spaces after GET returns error code \ expected output, not an exit code of 0)  But I still have the other two errors and moreover I am stuck at trying to find a solution how to determine correctness of the request line as per definition: method SP target SP http \r\n.....

Comment: also, I do not understand the meaning of the indicated errors: :( request-target of abc/hello.php returns error code 501 \ expected output, but not "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type:..."

:( Requesting cat.exe returns error code 501 \ expected output, not an exit code of 0                                                                                                         the solution you offer - using strchr to detect the delimeter - not sure how to implement it. In general I think I can solve if I understand what the errors mean....

Comment: These errors are written in a weird syntax :). I estimate :( request-target of abc/hello.php returns error code 501 \ expected output, but not "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type:..." means output for "request-target of abc/hello.php" should be error code 501 but your output was "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Type:..."

Comment: I will make an edit explaining use of strchr() in more detail.

Comment: for debugging what's happening when you request cat.exe and others. Put relevant breakpoints, start your program with "debug50 ./server ."   and at another terminal window use curl for your request like "curl -i http://localhost:8080/cat.exe"

Comment: thanks - when I use curl, the output is "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused"....

Comment: I think this is about permissions. change permission for directory and files where your server is running by using chmod command.